# Since Interface cannot inherit Class, then how "Object" class methods available to the interface reference in java?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

As per Object Oriented Programming (OOP) Interface should not inherit Class.

Since Interface cannot inherit Class, then how `Object` class methods available to the interface reference in java?

Eg :-

```
public interface Test {

    public void functionA();
}
class Child implements Test{

  public void functionA() {

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Test test = new Child();
     test.toString(); // since toString is Objects class method, How it's visible for Test interface ref?
  }
}
```

since `toString` is `Object`'s class method, How it's visible for `Test` interface ref?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every interface type is specified to implicitly declare all the public `Object` methods. That is how the Java Language Specification deals with this formality.

> ### [9.2. Interface Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2)
>
> ...
>
> - If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface implicitly declares a `public abstract` member method `m` with signature `s`, return type `r`, and `throws` clause `t` corresponding to each public instance method `m` with signature `s`, return type `r`, and `throws` clause `t` declared in `Object`, unless an abstract method with the same signature, same return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by the interface.

Answer (score 6):

Interface do not inherit from `Object` class in Java and there is no common `Object` (root) interface implicitly inherited by all interfaces either (as all classes do)

An interface has one implicit method declared for each public method in Object.

Refer Java Language Specification [9.2 Interface Members.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2)

Answer (score 0):

Every class you could possibly write implicitly inherits from `Object`.

Because interfaces (for example `java.util.List`) will for sure **reference** *some* object (of a class like `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` or some other implementation of `List` interface), Java let's you use `Object`'s methods.